# How to make the sum of two functions on the right side for function object?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have some code for numerical integration, it works fine, but I have a little question.
Here is my main.c code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "integral.h"

double func(double x) {
    return sin(x) + cos(x);
}

int main(void) {
    double a = 0;
    double b = 1;
    int steps = 5;
    double (*f)(double x);
    f = func;
    double i = integrate(f, a, b, steps);
    printf("%lf", i);
}
```

And this is how my integration function looks like: 
`double integrate(double(*f)(double x), double a, double b, int steps);`

So, my question: is there any way to code look like this[without func()]:

```
    double a = 0;
    double b = 1;
    int steps = 5;
    double (*f)(double x);
    f = sin + cos;
    double i = integrate(f, a, b, steps);
```

Comment: No. When you specify a function name without `()` after it, (e.g. `cos`) this means "address of function" (as if you did `&cos`). If you want some speed, add `static inline` to `func`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in C :).

That `+` is a pretty high-level construct, usually called an "operator". To do what you're asking, you'd need a way to redefine builtin syntax. When the compiler sees `+`, it would look up the meaning of that symbol, based on the arguments on either side. In C++ you'd write an `operator+` method, in Python an `__add__` method, in Rust you'd `impl Add`, and so on for other languages.

But unfortunately, there are no such niceties in C. Or *fortunately*, depending on your stance, since the above can get very complicated very quickly. C is, for better or worse, small, simple, dangerous, and fast.

Comment: Ah, I get it. I thought this could work, because I wrote similar thing in Java.